# Querying join with Mikro-orm

Tags: sql, node.js, mikro-orm

I'm trying to get `Author` details such that his/her book category is 'Science' and either price is > 20 or pages > 300.

```
*Author*
id
name
country
books

*Book*
id
name
category
price
edition
pages
author_id
```

With query like:

```
authorRepository.find(filter, {})
```

and `filter` as:

```
{
     "books": {
         "$and": [{
                 "category": {
                     "$eq": "Science"
                 }
             }, {
                 "$or": [{
                         "price": { $eq: 20 }
                     }, {
                         "pages": { $gt: 300 }
                     }
                 ]
             }
         ]
     }
 }
```

SQL query becomes:

```
select "e0"."*" from "author" as "e0" left join "book" as "e1" on "e0"."id" = "e1"."author_id" 
where "e1"."category" = 'Science' and ("e0"."price" = 20 or "e0"."pages" > 300)
```

Not sure why nested `$or` conditions are applied on `e0` (`Author`) instead of `e1` (`Book`).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug, but I believe it should work fine when you move the group operators to the top level. You don't need to use `$and` as that is implicit, as well as `$eq`, so simplified version could look like this:

```
const filter = {
  books: { category: 'Science' },
  $or: [
    { books: { price: 20 } },
    { books: { pages: { $gt: 300 } } },
  ],
};
```